# want div to load immediately after the image above it is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, featherlight.js

I want  to load at the same time, or immediately after the image above it. It keeps loading before the image and the caption div spins around inside the preloader - no good! Here is the html:

```
<div id="modalContent" class="featherlight-content">

    <span class="featherlight-close-icon featherlight-close">✕</span>

    <img src="http://johnhoich.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/John-Hoich-30.jpg" alt="" class="featherlight-image featherlight-inner" style="width: 965.457px; height: 584px;">

    <div class="modal-caption" style="display: block;">
        Various investments in stock, portfolio managed by John L. Hoich, T.D. Ameritrade, Kevin Welch/Morgan Stanley
    </div>
</div>
```

Using js - how can I get  to load immediately after the image is loaded?

Comment: Add an `onload` in the `img` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html:

```
<img onLoad="onMyImgLoad()" src="http://johnhoich.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/John-Hoich-30.jpg" alt="" class="featherlight-image featherlight-inner" style="width: 965.457px; height: 584px;" />
```

In your Javascript:

```
var mydiv = document.querySelector(".modal-caption");
mydiv.style.display = "none"; // Hide by default

var onMyImgLoad = function(){
   mydiv.style.display = "block"; // Show on img loaded
};
```

Comment: thanks for this! I used the onLoad="function" and then made the function .show the image. So I used a mixture of what you suggested. Appreciate your input

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `jQuery`'s [`.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) function, like this:

```js
$("img").load(function() {
  $(".modal-caption").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="modalContent" class="featherlight-content">

  <span class="featherlight-close-icon featherlight-close">✕</span>

  <img src="http://johnhoich.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/John-Hoich-30.jpg" alt="" class="featherlight-image featherlight-inner" style="width: 965.457px; height: 584px;">

  <div class="modal-caption" style="display: none;">Various investments in stock, portfolio managed by John L. Hoich, T.D. Ameritrade, Kevin Welch/Morgan Stanley</div>
</div>
```

And must make your `.modal-caption` hidden by default be setting its `display` to `none`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you need is:

1. Hide the `div` what you want to appear after (CSS)
2. Using `onload` or jQuery's `.load()` function show the hidden `div`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".loader").load(function() {
      $(".modal-caption").show();
    });
});
```

```css
.modal-caption{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="modalContent" class="featherlight-content">

    <span class="featherlight-close-icon featherlight-close">✕</span>

    <img class="loader" src="http://johnhoich.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/John-Hoich-30.jpg" alt="" class="featherlight-image featherlight-inner" style="width: 965.457px; height: 584px;">

    <div class="modal-caption" style="display: block;">
        Various investments in stock, portfolio managed by John L. Hoich, T.D. Ameritrade, Kevin Welch/Morgan Stanley
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question through trial and error.

**Solution:**

I used the onLoad in the img html:

```
<img onload="loadImage()" src="/Omaha-Westside-High-School.png" alt=""
class="featherlight-image featherlight-inner" style="width: 344.188px; 
height: 190px;">
```

Then for js I used:

```
function loadImage() {
      $(".modal-caption").show();
}
```